# Smoke from the fusebox switch but everything seems be working

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

I was replacing an electrical fixture and I had turned off the circuit (one with support for arc testing) on the electrical panel. When I turned it back on, it made some noise/ some smoke came. I immediately turned it off again/ check the fixture wirings etc.. And, then turned the circuit back on. This time there was no smoke and everything seems to be working.

I would like to understand the source of the smoke/ check if all is well.

Comment: Where did the smoke emanate from?  Are there any burn marks present there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some termonolog may be in order, your service panel or breaker panel is where you installed an arc fault device? Don't know of any fuse box versions. Did you have the breaker turned off when you snapped it in? A load on a breaker when inserted can cause an arc flash with smoke and maybe minor damage to the buss or breaker. Since things now work it may be fine but I would want to inspect the buss and contacts on the breaker if all looks good it may have been a minor arc that did not cause harm that would make it unsafe.